# Study the Convergence of $\sum \sqrt{n+a} - \sqrt[4]{n^2 + 2n}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, convergence-divergence

First of all let $a \in R$

I tried using the root test and got nowhere. Also tried by comparisson but I get stuck. The last thing I tried is to rewrite the series as follows:
$$
\sum (\sqrt{n+a} - \sqrt[4]{n^2 + 2n}) =
\sum \frac{n+a - \sqrt{n^2 + 2n}}{\sqrt{n+a} + \sqrt[4]{n^2 + 2n}}
$$
since I've seen lots of problems similar to this being treated this way. I assume that I need to compare it to a $p$-series. I need a hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the fact that $x^4-y^4=(x-y)(x^3+x^2y+xy^2+y^3)$. So:\begin{multline}\sqrt{n+a}-\sqrt[4]{n^2+2n}=\sqrt[4]{n^2+2an+a^2}-\sqrt[4]{n^2+2n}=\\=\frac{2an-2n+a^2}{\sqrt[4]{n^2+2an+a^2}^3+\sqrt[4]{n^2+2an+a^2}^2\sqrt[4]{n^2+2n}+\sqrt[4]{n^2+2an+a^2}\sqrt[4]{n^2+2n}^2+\sqrt[4]{n^2+2n}^3}\end{multline}Since the denominator behaves as $4n^{\frac32}$, the series converges if $a=1$ and diverges otherwise.

Comment: Nice alternative way!

Comment: @gimusi I'm glad you enjoyed it.

Comment: How do i realise that the denominator behaves like $4n^{\frac{4}{3}}$ and, what happens with the nominator? Is there another whay to confront the series? by comparison or any other test? I usally dont realise when "some thing behave like this or that", if makes any sense what i'm saying. Thanks

Comment: @Karl If $n$ is large, the denominator is basically$$(n^2)^{\frac34}+(n^2)^{\frac24}(n^2)^{\frac14}+(n^2)^{\frac14}(n^2)^{\frac24}+(n^2)^{\frac34}\simeq4n^{\frac32}.$$The numerator behaves like $(2a-2)n$ if $n\neq1$ and like $a^2$ otherwise. Therefore, you can apply the comparaison test with the series $\sum_{n\geqslant1}\frac{(2a-2)n}{4n^{\frac32}}=\sum_{n\geqslant1}\frac{a-1}{2\sqrt n}$ if $a\neq1$ and with the series $\sum_{n\geqslant1}\frac{a^2}{4n^{\frac32}}$ otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Note that by binomial expansion

- $\sqrt{n+a}=\sqrt n(1+a/n)^\frac12=\sqrt n+\frac{a}{2\sqrt n}-\frac{a^2}{8n\sqrt n}+o\left(\frac{1}{n\sqrt n}\right)$
- $\sqrt[4]{n^2+2n}=\sqrt n(1+2/n)^\frac14=\sqrt n+\frac1{2\sqrt n}-\frac{3a^2}{8n\sqrt n}+o\left(\frac{1}{n\sqrt n}\right)$

then

$$\sqrt{n+a} - \sqrt[4]{n^2 + 2n}=\frac1{2\sqrt n}\left(a-1\right)+\frac{a^2}{4n\sqrt n}+o\left(\frac{1}{n\sqrt n}\right)$$

and for $a\neq 1$ the series diverges and converges for $a=1$.

Comment: $\sim$ has a very precise meaning. Please be less sloppy with your asymptotic expansions and write the correct error terms.

Comment: @GabrielRomon What symbol do you suggest to keep a short notation, assuming that it is a hint to further elaborated by the asker.I can complete if you think that this way is misleading.

Comment: @GabrielRomon What about now! I hope that now it is less sloppy!

Comment: yes, definitely better. For the sake of simplicity I would stop at $O(\frac 1{n\sqrt n})$ though.

Comment: Yes you are right, it is not necessary to give he full expression for higher order terms.

Answer (score 0):

Go on:
\begin{align}
\sum (\sqrt{n+a} - \sqrt[4]{n^2 + 2n}) &=
\sum \frac{n+a - \sqrt{n^2 + 2n}}{\sqrt{n+a} + \sqrt[4]{n^2 + 2n}} \\[6px]
&=\sum\frac{n^2+2an+a^2-n^2-2n}{(\sqrt{n+a} + \sqrt[4]{n^2 + 2n})(n+a + \sqrt{n^2 + 2n})} \\[6px]
&=\sum \frac{2(a-1)n+a^2}{
n\sqrt{n}(\sqrt{1+a/n}+\sqrt[4]{1+2/n})(1+a/n+\sqrt{1+2/n})
}
\end{align}

Comment: Very elegant your proof.